# Is the IEnumerator of a dictionary guaranteed to be consistent?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, ienumerable

So, I've found a piece of code like this:

```
class CustomDictionary
{
  Dictionary<string, string> backing;
  ...
  public string Get(int index)
  {
    return backing.ElementAtOrDefault(index); //use linq extensions on IEnumerable
  }
}
```

And then this was used like so:

```
for(int i=0;i<mydictionary.Count;i++)
{
  var value=mydictionary.Get(i);
}
```

Aside from the performance problems and uglyness of doing it this way, is this code actually correct? Ie, is the IEnumerable on Dictionary guaranteed to always return things in the same order assuming that nothing is modified with the dictionary during the iteration?

Comment: I suggest you decompiling the Dictionary class as it depends solely on the internal implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is NOT guaranteed. It is for a SortedDictionary<>, of course, and also for arrays and lists. But NOT for a Dictionary.

Chances are, it will be stable if the dictionary is not changed - but it's just not guaranteed. You have to ask yourself - do you feel lucky? ;)

Comment: Dovie'andi se tovya sagain.. I especially like "do you feel lucky?"

Comment: SortedDictionary will not garantee you get the items for the same sequence you used to add them to the data structure. It will sort the items by the key provided.

Comment: @MiguelMatos: If the keys have an unambiguous ranking, and if items are neither added nor removed, repeated enumeration must return all the items in the same sequence (the one and only correct one).

Comment: @supercat Well it depends on what kind of sequence you want. If you want the items sorted by key or you want the items sorted by the order they were add. The way the question was made is not clear what sort Earlz is looking for.

Comment: @MiguelMatos: My interpretation was that he didn't need any particular sequence, but he needed all of the `ElementAtOrDefault` calls returned distinct items.

Comment: @MiguelMatos that is correct. Order doesn't matter as long as it's consistent

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the elements by the order they were inserted then you should probably look into the [Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx) and [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) depending on what elements you want first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you'll get the same items.

As you specified, the method you presented is very inefficient way to do so.

ElementAtOrDefault is a LINQ extension method for IEnumerable, means for each item it will iterate all way to the specified item.